# 115 volts vs 240 volts

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am a novice and are working on a project . I need to get a view point of if im heading in the correct direction. My question is:
Can I put two 115 volt 2 hp motors through a step down out of a 240 volt 16 amp house point?

Comment: Wrong Direction.  Each 2Hp 115Vac motor needs a 20A breaker preferably on different lines if you intend to operate them together to reduce Neutral drop. and balance the lines

Comment: Please edit your question to include name plate information from your motors. Ideally, you would include a clear picture so we can read all the name plate data. It would also be helpful if you added a diagram to your question to show exactly what you are considering.

Answer (score 2):

2HP is 1500W and two therefore is 3000W.

With an RMS current limit of 16A your motor power factor (including any correction) has to be better than 0.78 for it to not risk blowing an breaker under continuous run conditions.

Of course you'd need an appropriately rated (eg. 4kVA) 240:120 transformer, and the start-up surges might blow breakers.

You may also have to correct for efficiency, depending on how the motor is rated. You definitely have to correct if the rating meets IEC/NEMA standards, as mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: Plus, 1500W is the output power. In addition to power factor you have to account for the less than 100% efficiency.

Comment: @mkeith Good point- are single phase motors typically rated in power input or shaft power? (ignoring the "Sears Horsepower" exaggerations, that is).

Comment: As far as I know, as long as the motor has a name plate, the rated power is output power. For sure, at least small single phase induction motor name plate power is the output power. Rated power = full load amps * rated voltage * PF * eff. This is from looking at pool pump and table-saw motors and such like.

Comment: NEMA and IEC standards both require the rated output power to be marked on the nameplate. They require rated input voltage, current and power factor to be marked but do not require marking the input power rating.